# Bootstrap columns look weird

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some problems with my bootstrap columns, please check this screenshot to see what I'm talking about.

http://prntscr.com/9g11ua

Shouldn't the columns be inline?

Comment: Try just this `col-md-6` on both divs

Comment: It doesn't work, just tried that. I added a new class next to row with display: inline-block and it works, but I think the default bootstrap should have that for columns already

Comment: Please add the [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go one line before the problematic column and add this:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-<the size of the column>"></div>
```

for instance: let's say that the problem happens when the size of the column(lg-6) goes from lg to md then you need to put the problematic situation like so:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```

let me know if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added padding to children of first div having col-lg-6 class?